# Using meta_query in add_query_arg

Tags: wp-admin, meta-query

I'm trying to filter a list of post by clicking on value listed in a custom column.

To get that I'm using this:

```
$minisite = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'post_type' => $post->post_type,
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                            array('key' => 'minisite_actu_cat',
                                            'value' => $idParentPost,
                                            'compare' => 'REGEXP' )
                                            )
                                ), 'edit.php' ) ),
    esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $parentPost->post_title, $post->ID, 'publications-type', 'display' ) )
                );
```

In my case, the value are like that:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"522";}
```

In my URL I got this:

```
wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=msactus&meta_query[0][key]=minisite_actu_cat&meta_query[0][value]=522&meta_query[0][compare]
```

But it doens't filter at all.
I tried to display the request and I got this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS BIEVREISERE_posts.ID FROM BIEVREISERE_posts WHERE 1=1 AND BIEVREISERE_posts.post_type = 'msactus' AND (BIEVREISERE_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR BIEVREISERE_posts.post_status = 'future' OR BIEVREISERE_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR BIEVREISERE_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR BIEVREISERE_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY BIEVREISERE_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

I don't know why my meta query doesn't work.

Doesn't anyone got an idea?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the normal and expected behaviour to me. `meta_query` is not a registered query var. You can see a list of registered query vars, and their relationship with WP_Query in [this codex entre](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars). Any other query var you want to use needs to be registered and handled by you.

A very quick and general example:

```
// Add custom query var
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'cyb_add_query_vars' );
function cyb_add_query_vars( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = 'my_meta_query';
  return $vars;
}

// Manipulate query
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cyb_pre_get_posts' );
function cyb_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // Only main query?
    // if( $query->is_main_query() ) ...
    // Only admin?
    // if( is_admin() ) ....
    // Or whatever, you can manipulate $query as you wish

    if( ! empty( get_query_var( 'my_meta_query' ) ) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_query', get_query_var( 'my_meta_query' ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks cybmeta. But if I do that it doesn't manage to get all the data. For example, after setting my meta_query I've display my $query object and my meta_query is an empty array.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In `pre_get_posts` action you can manipulated the `$query` (a `WP_Query` obect) **as you wish, no limits**. If the `meta_query` is empty is because you have a set an empty or incorrect value, have you check it?

Comment: Yes I've chek it after. So that's why I closed this topic. Thanks a lot for your help cybmeta!